# The Master combinations in Dr Who the Card Game

Tags: doctor-who-the-card-game

When attacking with **The Master** it says that it can be *combined with any enemy card*.

So when I place The Master first: **does it mean I can add any enemy?**

If so, then when I attack with a certain enemy and place The Master with it in succeeding turns, can I still add another card to combine with The Master?

Answer (score 3):

Based on the rulebook it stated there

> You can add Enemy cards to one of your attacks, as long as the card
>   or cards you play can be legally played with the cards already in
>   place

Based on my understanding, if *The Master* is already in play along with another enemy, the enemy card you are going to add **should** be legally played with the cards. (meaning all of the cards) including the other enemy cards with *The Master*.